# Error in .jcall("weka/filters/Filter", "Weka/core/Instances;", "useFilter", : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java, r, feature-selection, mlr

I am trying to execute the following code to filter features using mlr as shown in [here](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/feature_selection/index.html#filter-methods)

```
fv = generateFilterValuesData(classifTask,  method = c("information.gain", "chi.squared"))
```

But I get the following error **although the specified attribute is numeric** in the dataset Task(classifTask)

> Error in .jcall("weka/filters/Filter", "Weka/core/Instances;",
>   "useFilter", : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A nominal attribute
>   (weighted_rev) cannot have duplicate labels

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, reproducible example please?

Comment: So the code from the tutorial you linked does not fail for you? Then it seems to be something specific with your `classifTask` so we need an example that  breaks.